# Replacement for Chrome SSO flags

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on

I've been using the Chrome flags `auth-server-whitelist` and `auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist` to enable SSO on my corporate domains, but after the latest update to Chrome 41.0.2272.76m, these flags no longer work and SSO is disabled. I found an issue tracker at https://codereview.chromium.org/836843003 which describes the change but does not offer any remediation option. I've tried running through the settings and flags page to see if there are new options to set these flags but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how to get SSO enabled in Chrome after the above-mentioned update? In my opinion, this should just work out of the box mirroring how IE does it. If not, the option really needs to be more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to this is some registry entries:

- Software\Policies\Chromium\AuthServerWhitelist
- Software\Policies\Chromium\AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist

Reference: https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthServerWhitelist

You can also download administrative templates from [here](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates) and edit the settings in group policy from this branch in gpedit.msc:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Classic Administrative Templates (ADM) > Google > Google Chrome > Policies for HTTP Authentication > Authentication server whitelist

Just set it enabled and fill in your comma-separated domain list.

Comment: I don't see anything called "Chromium" in my registry. There also doesn't seem to be anything related to Google Chrome under any Software/Policies/ directories. Any advice on how to find the location for these entries? Do I need to create them myself?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create them yourself.